# What is the best practice fro a WCF, NHibernate, WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf, nhibernate, design-patterns, architecture

I'm not really into design pattern and I am take to it, Recently I found

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/wcfbyexample_introduction.aspx

and I'm thinking that is it really a robust practice or not? I'm going to use it in an enterprise application, Actually I suggest it to my project manager. I'm not sure that is it a robust and reliable pattern or not.

Is there any better solution for a WCF, WPF, NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project scale and many other factors, but as I know all in all it is an easy to understand solution for those who don't want to use an in-house framework.

I'm not sure that you can find a better free solution than this however this is reaaly good

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use WCF and WPF, you could also opt to use Entity Framework instead of NHibernate, as to stay with Microsoft technologies. Maybe it's easier to convince your project manager if you suggest Entity Framework, as it is (should be) completely compatible with WCF.

It's actually pretty easy to set up a WCF Service with Entity Framework. Don't know about NHibernate, it's been a while since I used it myself.

Bu the baseline is the same, Entity or NHibernate. It's considered best practice to separate your layers, and in the end it doesn't matter which technology you use for each layer.

Comment: In which way is EF more compatible with WCF than other ORMs?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is more compatible, but it is definately easier to use in a **Microsoft stack**. eg: the wizards which are provided in Visual Studio. Also, when creating an WcfDataService for example, you get seamless integration with a new or existing (EF) DataContext. Sure, that also works with other ORMs, it's just easier to work with and maintain I think. (note: I'm not against using other ORMs, I use them daily, they all have their pros and contras).

Comment: Also, LINQ To Entity Framework makes it very easy to query, retrieve and update objects in EF.